# Register lock and unlock events on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process

I have been re-searching a lot on this topic and haven't found a clear answer yet, so I will just ask straight forward:

Is it possible to detect/register screen lock and screen unlock events while my iOS application runs in the background ?

The main idea is that the application should be able register how long the phone was inactive (while is locked).

My first thought is to have some sort of background process that will register the lock/unlock events, but I am afraid that the OS will kill that process after some time and I wouldn't be able to complete the whole scenario. Next question raising here is - Does Apple allows stuff like that on the AppStore ?